React Native - TypeError: window.addEventListener is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes
I have an expo project, and setting up a clerk auth. I have followed all the required code clerk gave, and now getting this error on the links. Everything looks okay to me, but I cant figure out how to solve this issue. Im not building a web page, and i dont have addEventListener in my code anywhere. I dont know why is this happening.
with this folder structure:

The Error:
TypeError: window.addEventListener is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes 
    at ContextNavigator (http://10.40.105.10:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:145624:24)
    at ExpoRoot (http://10.40.105.10:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:145580:28)
    at App
    at ErrorToastContainer (http://10.40.105.10:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:236490:24)
    at ErrorOverlay
    at withDevTools(ErrorOverlay) (http://10.40.105.10:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:235993:27)
    at RCTView
    at View (http://10.40.105.10:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:41520:43)
    at RCTView
    at View (http://10.40.105.10:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:41520:43)
    at AppContainer (http://10.40.105.10:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:41363:25)
    at main(RootComponent) (http://10.40.105.10:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:119719:28)


app/_layout.tsx
import FontAwesome from "@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome";
import {
  DarkTheme,
  DefaultTheme,
  ThemeProvider,
} from "@react-navigation/native";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import "react-native-reanimated";
import { useColorScheme } from "@/components/useColorScheme";

import * as SecureStore from "expo-secure-store";
import { ClerkProvider, ClerkLoaded } from "@clerk/clerk-expo";

const tokenCache = {
  async getToken(key: string) {
    try {
      const item = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(key);
      if (item) {
        console.log(`${key} was used  \n`);
      } else {
        console.log("No values stored under key: " + key);
      }
      return item;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("SecureStore get item error: ", error);
      await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync(key);
      return null;
    }
  },
  async saveToken(key: string, value: string) {
    try {
      return SecureStore.setItemAsync(key, value);
    } catch (err) {
      return;
    }
  },
};

const CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY!;

if (!CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY) {
  throw new Error(
    "Missing Publishable Key. Please set EXPO_PUBLIC_CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY in your .env",
  );
}

export {
  // Catch any errors thrown by the Layout component.
  ErrorBoundary,
} from "expo-router";

export const unstable_settings = {
  // Ensure that reloading on `/modal` keeps a back button present.
  initialRouteName: "/",
};

// Prevent the splash screen from auto-hiding before asset loading is complete.
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

function InitialLayout() {
  const [loaded, error] = useFonts({
    SpaceMono: require("../assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf"),
    ...FontAwesome.font,
  });

  // Expo Router uses Error Boundaries to catch errors in the navigation tree.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) throw error;
  }, [error]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loaded) {
      SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [loaded]);

  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Stack>
      <Stack.Screen name="sign-in" />
      <Stack.Screen name="sign-up" />
    </Stack>
  );
}

function RootLayoutNav() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <ClerkProvider
      tokenCache={tokenCache}
      publishableKey={CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY}
    >
      <ClerkLoaded>
        <InitialLayout />
      </ClerkLoaded>
    </ClerkProvider>
  );
}
export default RootLayoutNav;



app/(auth)/_layout.tsx
import { Redirect, Stack } from 'expo-router'
import { useAuth } from '@clerk/clerk-expo'

export default function AuthRoutesLayout() {
  const { isSignedIn } = useAuth()

  if (isSignedIn) {
    return <Redirect href={'/'} />
  }

  return <Stack />
}

app/(home)/index.tsx
import { SignedIn, SignedOut, useUser } from '@clerk/clerk-expo'
import { Link } from 'expo-router'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'

export default function Page() {
  const { user } = useUser()

  return (
    <View>
      <SignedIn>
        <Text>Hello {user?.emailAddresses[0].emailAddress}</Text>
      </SignedIn>
      <SignedOut>
        <Link href="./sign-in">
          <Text>Sign In</Text>
        </Link>
        <Link href="./sign-up">
          <Text>Sign Up</Text>
        </Link>
      </SignedOut>
    </View>
  )
}


See https://github.com/clerk/javascript/issues/4084.

I also had this issue and found this reply from the clerk team on a discord channel:
"This is a known issue in our latest version of @clerk/clerk-expo and we have a patch coming out in the next release.
For the time being, we are advising users to use version 2.2.5 where this issue is not present.
Apologies for the inconvenience here but please let us know if you have any other questions!"

What solved the problem was removing the ^ from "@clerk/clerk-expo": "^2.1.0" inside package.json
After the change it looked like this: "@clerk/clerk-expo": "2.1.0".
It solved the issue

I tried 2.2.5
good thing is the error is resolved,
bad thing is still there is a warning...
 WARN  Clerk: Clerk has been loaded with development keys. Development instances have strict usage limits and should not be used when deploying your application to production.


Spent like 2 hours trying various solutions, clearing cache, node_modules etc and trying out various lame solutions ChatGPT gave, downgrading to a previous version worked especially @clerk/clerk-expo": "^2.2.5.
People imagining AI taking jobs, remember there are some things only Chad developers can solve. Gratitude to everyone participating in this answer.
